# What standard and custom fields are indexed?

Tags: soql

I'm trying to find a proper list of what standard fields are indexed by default in salesforce, as well as under what conditions custom fields are indexed.

To start things off I know fields are indexed:

- When salesforce has added a custom index at your request (but you can't rely on this in other orgs)
- Any fields marked as external IDs
- Master-Detail fields
- Lookup fields
- System audit fields (CreatedDate, SystemModStamp)

I've asked salesforce support and there is no authoritative documentation on this outside of this page: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Comment: Would you consider the Id field as being indexed or just the primary key? Probably not what you were looking for.

I suspect many of the limits in place are driven by underlying indexes. Such as the number of formula or validation rule references you can have.

Comment: One omission from your list I can see is the Id field of all objects

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of the [Spring 15](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_field_indexed_column.htm) release of Salesforce, the easiest way to see which fields on a given object are indexed is to check for a "check" in the "Indexed" column in the list of an object's fields in Setup:

[image: Indexed Column in Object Fields list]

Answer (score 25):

From the page you linked

> The following fields are indexed by default: primary keys (Id, Name
>   and Owner fields), foreign keys (lookup or master-detail relationship
>   fields), audit dates (such as LastModifiedDate), and custom fields
>   marked as External ID or Unique.

That line answers both the "by default" and "under what conditions custom fields" aspects of your question. That's it.

### Update

Some additional information about which fields are automatically indexed and exceptions for those which cannot be indexed is available in the [Best Practices for Deployments with Large Data Volumes (PDF)](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/cce/ldv_deployments/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf) architecture documentation. (In addition to a ton of other great stuff.)

> The platform automatically maintains indexes on the following fields for most objects.
>
> - RecordTypeId
> - Division
> - CreatedDate
> - Systemmodstamp (LastModifiedDate)
> - Name
> - Email (for contacts and leads)
> - Foreign key relationships (lookups and master-detail)
> - The unique Salesforce record ID, which is the primary key for each object
>
> Salesforce also supports custom indexes on custom fields, with the exception of multi-select picklists, text area (long), text area (rich), non-deterministic formula fields, and encrypted text fields.
>
> External IDs cause an index to be created on that field, which is then considered by the Force.com query optimizer.
>
> External IDs can be created on only the following fields.
>
> - Auto Number
> - Email
> - Number
> - Text
>
> To create custom indexes for other field types, including standard
>   fields, contact salesforce.com Customer Support

Comment: I've heard plenty of back and forth that some standard fields are indexed as well, any idea on if that's true or not?

Comment: Beyond what is in the documentation I do not know. Unless there are core Salesforce developers active here not sure we'll get an answer on that. I would take the line that the documentation is correct until such time as a reliable and verifiable source says otherwise. If you need indexes added else where for your org you can always request it.

Comment: We've requested indexes on Lead.Email and Lead.Phone standard fields and been denied.

Comment: `RecordTypeId` and `Division` are also indexed where appropriate. `Email` is indexed on `Contact` and `Lead`.

Comment: @ca_peterson, added some additional details to this about the fields which are automatically indexed... if you're still curious about this info two years later!

Comment: SystemModStamp field is indexed and LastModifiedDate is not. The above post seems to be referring to both of them. There is difference between these two fields. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386977&type=1

Answer (score 14):

Just found that salesforce has posted a cheat sheet with much more data about indexing than I've ever seen before. Take a look at the [Query & Search Optimization Fields Cheat Sheet](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/SF_Query_Search_cheatsheet_web.pdf) on the [developerforce wiki's cheat sheet area](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Cheat_Sheets).

One big takeaway is that there are some substantial differences between performance of standard and custom indexes.

Fields that have standard index applied:

- Custom lookup fields
- Custom master-detail fields
- Id
- Name
- Owner
- Audit dates
- On standard objects there are some others that aren't documented anywhere

Custom indexes:

- Can be added by salesforce support
- External Id fields
- Unique fields

Comment: Odd that it isn't at http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Cheat_Sheets

Comment: Thanks for referring to the cheat sheet, ca_peterson. Mike, the cheat sheet does now appear at http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Cheat_Sheets, where it also has a new "salesforce.com" link.

Comment: The sheet is now available at: http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf