# How can I find out what custom indexes have been created in my Org?

Tags: indexing, custom-index

In orgs with large data volumes, it sometimes becomes necessary to ask Salesforce to [create a custom index](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006227&language=en_US) on a particular field, or combination of fields.

Once Salesforce creates a custom index, is there any way for a System Administrator to see that it, or any other custom index actually exists?  It seems like the only way to do this right now is to contact Salesforce Support and ask them.

**Please Note:** I'm wondering specifically about *custom indexes*, which are only created by opening a case with Salesforce, and not default indexes.  This question, ["What standard and custom fields are indexed?"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218/what-standard-and-custom-fields-are-indexed) does a great job listing fields that get indexed by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, as of August 2014, the only way to find out if a custom index exists is to open a case with Salesforce Support and ask them whether or not a **specific** field is indexed.

Apparently, the Setup UI of the support reps has a "Column Indexed" checkbox on their version of a Field detail page.  This is how they are able to check if a particular field has an index. Makes me wonder what a two column index looks like on their screen...

**Update:** This feature has now gone GA. The Fields setup pages for Standard Objects, and the main setup pages for Custom Objects now display an "Indexed" checkbox for all standard and custom fields.

[image: Screen capture showing the new "Indexed" attribute for standard and custom fields]

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific field in mind, you could use the Query Plan tool to verify that it is there.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000199003&language=en_US

that won't help you browse for arbitrary indexes, but you could definitely use it to verify the existence of an index you expect to be there.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Sean! I hadn't thought of that.  Luckily, Salesforce made the question moot by making the "Indexed" checkbox GA.  Now we can find this information in Setup! :-)