# Is there a way to tell if custom indexes exist on an object?

Tags: soql, largedatavolumes, ldv, selectivity

I want to be able to design to use indexes and custom indexes where they exist.

Is there a way to tell if custom indexes have previously been created on a field?

Comment: have you gone thru this discussion already ? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218/what-standard-and-custom-fields-are-indexed

Comment: Thanks, but I think that is more about principles. I want a way to find out specifically, which fields have had custom indexes added to them previously by a dev/admin requesting this from support.