# Flow lookup runs into error

Tags: visual-workflow, lookup, fast-lookup

Friday runs my flow perfectly but today it doesn't work anymore. I reduced all settings of the flow to find the problem, but I get still the error.
My custom object (Einzelrisiko) has field (Name testid). the flow looks to see if it finds a suitable contact. At contact I have also the field testid.

I tried to reduce all other settings and to create new fields for the lookup, but it doesn't work anymore. It may be that the object is locked if there are frequent errors?

[image: flow1]

[image: flow2]

How the Interview Started
firstname lastname (005b0000000asp4) started the flow interview.
API Version for Running the Flow: 50
Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
$Record = Einzelrisiko__c (a0G0X00000NTrDtUAL)

FAST LOOKUP: test
Find all Contact records where:
testid__c Contains {!$Record.testid__c} (1234567)
Sort records by: Id (Ascending)
Store the values of these fields in test: Id
Result
Failed to find records.

Comment: Given it's changed over the weekend, have you checked whether your org went Spring'21 and if so, reviewed the release notes? This wouldn't happen to be running as a site guest user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that the lookup field was not indexed. Now I changed the setting from the field and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this is related to the problem you are experiencing but I recommend using equals instead of contains when dealing with Id’s. I am assuming there is a contact with that test id. If you cannot find the issue save your flow as an autolaunched flow so that you can debug. Then save again as a record-triggered flow after the fix. See here to see how it is done: https://youtu.be/8J4ahx2-wmg

Update based on your index comment: [What standard and custom fields are indexed?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218/what-standard-and-custom-fields-are-indexed)

I personally did not experience an issue related to indexing in similar use cases.

Comment: Contains was just a Test, usually I select equals.